# SQL Group By Date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing rows that I want to `Group By` days using `creationdate` column that has the following format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. How would I extract the yyyy-MM-dd part from this column (using `datetime` function?) so that this query would work:

`SELECT creationdate, count(*) as c FROM clients GROUP BY creationdate`.

Example table:

```
clients
---------------

id   name   creationdate

0    a      2015-03-01 10:11:58
1    b      2015-04-18 22:14:35
2    c      2015-04-18 14:25:07
```

The above query will output three groups but there should be two.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
select date(creationdate), count(*) as c from clients group by date(creationdate)
```